# How to preload a AudioClip in Java

Tags: java, performance, audio, libraries, preload

I use this class to play a song in my program:

```
public class Sound extends Thread {
    private static AudioClip song;

    public Sound(String songUrl) {

        try{
            URL songFile = SoundRessources.class.getResource(songUrl);
            song = Applet.newAudioClip(songFile);
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            System.out.println("impossible de trouver la musique");
        }

    }

    public void playSound() {
        song.play();    
    }
}
```

But when I play my sound like that:

```
new Sound("xxxxx/xxxx.wav").play();
```

It takes some seconds before the sound starts playing.

My question: Can i preload my sound? Maybe there is a library more responsive than this applet? Or have you got a better idea to play my sound instantly?

Comment: Take a look on SoundLoader part: http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/applet/ui/sound.html, it seems to be exactly what you ask for

Comment: Hi, i tried this code but the same thing is happening. When i click on the button, the sound is played 0,5 second later and not instantly

Comment: @Thibaultmarboud are you trying to use `Thread` because you want to play in background ?

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of `Thread` is very strange. In case you wanted to load clip in background thread, and then start playing you would need to change :

```
public class BackroundSound extends Thread {
    private String songUrl;

    public BackroundSound(String url) {
        songUrl = url;
    }

    //load in background and then start playing
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (songUrl == null) {
            // log error, url wasn't set
        }
        URL songFile = SoundRessources.class.getResource(songUrl);
        AudioClip song = Applet.newAudioClip(songFile);
        song.play();
        // log - playback is finished
    }
}
```

To load and play sound :

```
new BackroundSound("xxxxx/xxxx.wav").start();
```

Comment: Thanks ! I see my mistakes. But even if i use your class the sound is played  1-2 seconds later. It's annoying

Comment: How about this: you start loading your clip in background thread, say, when your application starts, while continuing regular user interaction for a few seconds. This way it will be ready when you need to play it (i.e. when user clicks play button or some other event, don't know what you want to do with it)

Comment: This is exactly what i do ! but the sound is always played some second after the action.

Comment: well, I guess i could try to help if you exlpain your app architecture with some relevant code snapshots.

Answer (score 1):

The sound can be preloaded as byte[].

in you Main class

```
ApplicationSound.setSplotchSound(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
              Main.class.getResourceAsStream("splotch-sound.wav")));
```

and in ApplicationSound

```
public class ApplicationSound
{
  private static byte[] splotchSound = { };
  private static AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(44100, 16, 2, true, false);

  public static void setSplotchSound(AudioInputStream audioInputStream)
  {
    try
    {
       splotchSound = audioInputStream.readAllBytes();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
       // nothing
    }
  }

  public static AudioInputStream getSplotchSound()
  {
     return new AudioInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(splotchSound),
        audioFormat, splotchSound.length);
  }
}
```

and within your application

```
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
              clip.open(ApplicationSound.getSplotchSound());
              clip.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my method to playback .wav audio files, they can be started without much delay.

```
// java -cp ./lib/mylib.jar SoundTest2 "clip1=rumble2.wav" "clip2=tos.wav"
// Type 1,2,q in a console and ENTER.
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class SoundTest2 {
    
    public Clip play(String filename, boolean autostart, float gain) throws Exception {
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(filename));
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInputStream);
        clip.setFramePosition(0);

        // values have min/max values, for now don't check for outOfBounds values
        FloatControl gainControl = (FloatControl)clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
        gainControl.setValue(gain);
        
        if(autostart) clip.start();
        return clip;
    }
    
//**************************************
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String,String> params = parseParams(args);
        SoundTest1 test1 = new SoundTest1();
                
        Clip clip1 = test1.play(params.get("clip1"), false, 3.0f);
        Clip clip2 = test1.play(params.get("clip2"), false, 3.0f);

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true) {
            Clip clip=null;
            String cmd=scanner.nextLine();
            if(cmd.equals("1")) clip=clip1;
            else if(cmd.equals("2")) clip=clip2;
            else if(cmd.equals("q")) break;
            
            if(clip!=null) {
                clip.setFramePosition(0);
                clip.start();
            }
        }
    }
    
    private static Map<String,String> parseParams(String[] args) {
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
        for(String arg : args) {
            int delim = arg.indexOf('=');
            if (delim<0) params.put("", arg.trim());
            else if (delim==0) params.put("", arg.substring(1).trim());
            else params.put(arg.substring(0, delim).trim(), arg.substring(delim+1).trim() );
        }
        return params;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Why would it be better to preload the audiofiles as clip's rather than as byte[] as in the other answer? Each clip has it's own thread. Would it matter that a lot of clip threads are kept open, in case there are many different sounds to display while the application is running? Anybody any idea?